# Show/Hide DOM element

Tags: angular

I'm developing a small app in Angular2 and I'm trying to make to make the following code work:

```
<tr *ngFor="let person of personArray"
      (mouseenter)="remove.hidden=true" (mouseleave)="remove.hidden=false">
    <td>
      <span #remove>...</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

1. For some reason nothing really happens. What's the problem?
2. I called the span element "remove" but the *ngFor creates multiples spans with the same name. Is this the right approach?

*I'm trying to avoid any additional code inside the class.

Comment: Your code did work for me: http://plnkr.co/edit/44zHGlI9DhQSbvrxfDnK?p=preview About 2: I'm not sure if we should use references within `*ngFor`, but the code did work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is, that once you enter table row with mouse, the span correctly dissapers. Immediately is *mouseleave* called since its hidden..

Here is working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/McjjDMdLIkiFGUkZ9lNu?p=preview

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template:  `
    <table>
      <tr *ngFor="let person of personArray"
            (mouseenter)="remove.hidden=true" (mouseleave)="remove.hidden=false">
          <td>
            <span #remove>{{ person }}</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  personArray: string[];

  constructor() {

      this.personArray = ["Bob", "Alice", "Seb"];
  }

}
```